# uncaught exception: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [href=example.html]

Tags: javascript, jquery

While testing my website in Firebug i get this error when clicking on a menu button:

uncaught exception: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [href=schedule.html]

I think it goes wrong here because the current class won't apply but the rest works fine.(these aren't the full code)

html:

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a class="current" href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="schedule.html">SCHEDULE</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

js:

```
$("nav a").removeClass("current");
$("nav a[href="+newHash+"]").addClass("current");
```

Comment: There is something wrong with your code. Unless you show the code, the only answers that you can get will be based on people guessing what your code might look like.

Comment: While I could take a guess … I'm not going to. If your code is throwing errors, then don't provide just the error. It is hard to identify problems in secret code we cannot see.

Comment: Firebug is already shown what is the wrong.

Comment: My guess: you forgot to wrap your selector in quotes: `$([href=schedule.html])`...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This looks like your culprit:

```
// add single quotes on your selector value 
$("nav a[href='"+newHash+"']").addClass("current");
```

Answer (score 3):

Since jquery 1.5, quoting attribute values is mandatory. You can quote with single or double quotes:

```
$("nav a[href='"+newHash+"']").addClass("current");
```

or

```
$('nav a[href="'+newHash+'"]').addClass("current");
```

Quoting was optional in jQuery 1.4 or lower.

Comment: The course I'm taking (Lynda.com -> jQuery Essential Training) uses a jQuery version that doesn't require these quotes yet. So in the video you see all is working fine without them but if you use a newer jQuery version, you do need them!